# runAction not moving my ship

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

My ship appears on the layer. When launch button is touched the ship is supposed to move to a calculated location. The touch is detected, the coordinates are correctly calculated, but the ship will not move. I have read the 500+ Q's and A's on this forum regarding runAction and nothing there helped me. I have also restarted Xcode and cleaned the targets.

Here is the interface for the ShipManager:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Common.h"//imports cocos2d.h

@interface ShipManager : NSObject {
    GameLayer *layer;
    CCSprite *ship;
    ...
    NSArray *shipTargetArray;
    CCArray *shipArray;
    int podValue;
    int podKey;
    int topPod;
    int botPod;
    float x;
    float y;    
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) CCSprite *ship;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CCSprite *pod;
...

-(id)initWith:(GameLayer *)gameLayer;
-(void)updateShip;
-(void)resetShip;
-(void)touchedExtinguishButton;    
@end
```

Parts of the implementation file:

```
#import "ShipManager.h"
#import "PodGroupManager.h"
#import "GameLayer.h"   

@implementation ShipManager

@synthesize ship;
...

int loadState;

//LAUNCH SHIP
-(void)launchShip {
    NSNumber *theTarget;
    CGPoint targetPosition;
    int shipTarget = absInt(topPod * botPod);

    theTarget = [NSNumber numberWithInt:shipTarget];
    NSInteger targetIndex = [shipTargetArray indexOfObject:theTarget];
    NSLog(@"target = %i; index = %i",shipTarget,targetIndex);//LOG:target = 20; index = 12

    self.ship = [shipArray objectAtIndex:0];//NEW CODE. 
    NSLog(@"ship tag = %i",ship.tag);//LOG:ship tag = 100
    NSLog(@"%@",shipArray);//LOG" <CCArray = 055209A0> = ( <CCSprite = 05520A40 | Rect = (2.00,2.00,148.00,200.00) | tag = 100 | atlasIndex = 10>, )

    x = ship.position.x;
    y = ship.position.y + 10 +34 * targetIndex;

    targetPosition = ccp(x,y);
    NSLog(@"target x = %f; y = %f",x, y);//LOG: target x = 384.000000; y = 754.000000

    //WHAT I WANT THE SHIP TO DO
    id action = [CCSequence actions:
              [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1.0f position:targetPosition],
              [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:1.0f],
              [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:.05f position:SHIP_START_POS],
              nil];
    [ship runAction:action];//SHIP DOES NOT MOVE*/
    //ALSO TRIED: [self.ship runAction:action]; NO MOVEMENT

    //ABOVE NOT WORKING -- TRYING SIMPLER MOVE
    //CCMoveTo* move = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1.0f position:targetPosition];
    //[ship runAction:move]; //TRYING SIMPLER ACTION - STILL NO MOVEMENT


    //JUST TRYING TO GET THE SHIP THERE
    //ship.position = targetPosition; //NO MOVEMENT EITHER

    if (missionState == SHIP_EXT) {
        NSLog(@"extinguish fuse");//logs button press correctly
    }       
}
...
//RESET SHIP TO LAUNCHING PAD
-(void)resetShip {
    ship.position = SHIP_START_POS;
    [self setShipState:SHIP_EMPTY];
    [self setMissionState:SHIP_IDLE];
    ship.visible = YES;
}

//SETUP SHIP
-(void) setupShip {
    shipArray  = [[CCArray alloc]initWithCapacity:1];//just added - latest attempt
    ship = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"ship.png"];

    [layer.batchNode addChild:ship z:SHIP_Z tag:SHIP_TAG];
    [shipArray addObject:ship];//just added - latest attempt
    [self resetShip];       
}
...
//INITIALIZE SHIPMANAGER
-(id)initWith:(GameLayer *)gameLayer {
    if ((self = [super init]) ) {
        layer = gameLayer;
        [self setupShip];
        ...         
        [self setTopPod:0];
        [self setBotPod:0];

        //MAKE SHIPTARGET ARRAY
        shipTargetArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                           [NSNumber numberWithInt:1],
                           ...
                           [NSNumber numberWithInt:25],
                           nil];
    }    
    return self;
}

-(void) dealloc {

    [shipTargetArray release];
    [shipArray release];
    self.ship = nil;

    [super dealloc];
}    
@end
```

I know that the launchShip method is being executed since all the NSLogs are printing as expected and the results are correct. I have 3 different options I have been trying in launchShip and I comment/uncomment them in turn to see if any work -- none do.
I'm new to Objective-c and cocos2d and I suspect that the issue is the way am trying to tell runAction what to run the action on. I'm sure there is a way to send the message properly and any help with what that proper way is would be so appreciated.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Before launching the ship, 2 fuel pods are loaded onto the ship. The fuel pods have numeric values. These values determine the ships target destination. All of that is working. The fuel pods are loaded and the correct destination is calculated.

Answer (score 0):

```
ship = [shipArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

This assignment will not retain. Change it to

```
self.ship = [shipArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

Later in the dealloc method do

```
self.ship = nil;
```

to release it. Treat the other variables (`shipTargetArray` `shipArray`) the same.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Tried it -- still does not work. Any other ideas?

Comment: @JoAnnC Can you update your code to the current state? And show some of the NSLog output?